# Add One to SQL Conditional

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query in SQL Server. I'd like to filter by a stored string (e.g. 5) or a stored string plus 1 (6). How can I do this?

```
SELECT  
  a1.A
  , a1.B
FROM Table a1
WHERE a1.C = ('<<<Tech>>>')
OR a1.C = ('CAST(CAST(<<<Tech>>> as int) + 1 AS varchar)')
AND a1.D <> 'DO_NOT_USE'
```

The above should result in data that I know in the table but it doesn't.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would make this much clearer.

Comment: If you need to do math with the value, _don't store it as a string_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the string '<>' is cast-able as an integer.

Here are 3 ways it could work:

1. Original except quotes

```
SELECT  
  a1.A
  , a1.B
FROM Table a1
WHERE a1.C = ('<<<Tech>>>')
OR a1.C = (CAST(CAST('<<<Tech>>>' as int) + 1 AS varchar))
AND a1.D <> 'DO_NOT_USE'
```

2. CROSS APPLY

```
SELECT a1.A, a1.B
FROM TableName a1
     cross apply
     (select CAST(CAST('<<<Tech>>>' as int) + 1 AS varchar) plus_one) p1
where a1.C = ('<<<Tech>>>')
      or a1.C=p1.plus_one
      and a1.D <> 'DO_NOT_USE';
```

3. Declared

```
declare
  @string_int        varchar(12)='<<<Tech>>>';
declare
  @plus_one         varchar(12)=CAST(CAST(@string_int as int) + 1 AS varchar);

SELECT a1.A, a1.B
FROM TableName a1
where a1.C = @string_int
      or a1.C=@plus_one
      and a1.D <> 'DO_NOT_USE';
```